# How do I get a list of cache names in Ehcache 3

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-3

In *Ehcache 2* I used

```
Cache<String, Release> releaseCache = cacheManager.getCacheNames();
```

But in *Ehcache 3* although I have a CacheManager the getCacheNames() method does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed. It does not exist. You have these solutions:

1. Do harsh reflection to get access to `EhCacheManager.caches`
2. Use JSR-107 `CacheManager.getCacheNames`

Comment: So 2. would be the sensible solution

Comment: But I dont understand why it was removed from Ehache 3 if it was in 2.

Comment: Because the method did not really cover a use case and was encouraging bad practices with cache managers and caches. If you have a valid use case, I would suggest starting a conversation on the user mailing list.

Comment: Well the (seemingly) valid use case was to check what caches we currently had configured, doesnt seem so crazy

Comment: If it is so poor why is it included in JSR-107 ?

Answer (score 0):

The only valid use-case for listing all caches by name is when that is for monitoring purposes. Ehcache 2 encouraged bad practices by tightly coupling caches to their name, which Ehcache 3 totally prevents.

If your use-case is to list caches for monitoring reasons, you should have a look at the not officially supported but nevertheless working monitoring API. There's a sample available over here: https://github.com/anthonydahanne/ehcache3-samples/blob/management-sample/management-sample/src/main/java/org/ehcache/management/sample/EhcacheWithMonitoring.java

Here's a brief example of how to use it to find out the existing cache names:

```
DefaultManagementRegistryService managementRegistry = new DefaultManagementRegistryService();

CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
    .using(managementRegistry)
    .withCache(...)
    .withCache(...)
    .build(true);

Capability settingsCapability = managementRegistry.getCapabilities().stream().filter(c -> "SettingsCapability".equals(c.getName())).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No SettingsCapability"));
for (Settings descriptor : settingsCapability.getDescriptors(Settings.class)) {
  String cacheName = descriptor.getString("cacheName");
  if (cacheName == null) {
    continue; // not a cache
  }
  System.out.println("cache : " + cacheName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand why is it bad practise to get Cache by name then, what are you meant to get them by.

Comment: Getting a cache by name isn't bad practice. Using a cache's name for any other purpose is.

Comment: Ludovic, what version of what jar files provide DefaultManagementRegistryService and Capability?  I have ehcache 3.9 and hibernate 5.6.2.Final (.jar and sources), not seeing any references to those classes.